# How do I display the video duration of the search results using Youtube API v3?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am able to return search results from the Youtube API.

How would I display the duration of the searched results? I do not see the duration anywhere in the json data.

```
function ySearch(e) {
    let searchYt = searchTermYt.value;
    search = encodeURIComponent(searchYt);
    let urlYt = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search/?part=snippet&type=video&key=' + apiYt + '&q=' + searchYt + '&maxResults=5';

    if (e.target.token) { 
        urlYt += '&pageToken='+e.target.token;
    }
    fetch(urlYt).then(function (response) {
        return response.json() 
    }).then(function (data) {
        // check for page token to enable or disable page buttons
        if(data.prevPageToken){ 
            btnPrev.token = data.prevPageToken;
            btnPrev.disabled = false;
        }else{
            btnPrev.token = false;
            btnPrev.disabled = true;
        }
        if(data.nextPageToken){ 
            btnNext.token = data.nextPageToken;
            btnNext.disabled = false;
        }else{
            btnNext.token = false;
            btnNext.disabled = true;
        }
        return data.items.map(function (x) {
            return {
                title: x.snippet.title,
                // use id in URL to watch video 
                id: x.id.videoId

            }
        })
    }).then(function (array) {
        renderData(array);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The search results do not contain the video duration. You have to take the videoIDs from the search results and make another call to [Videos:list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) using the videoIDs and the part parameter 'contentDetails'.

Example: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=gVLsVj7BebE&key=API_KEY

will return

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/CbYwR7FePSZfjlzY4mNeMODOwJA\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/9xoE3Yy_gyWHNwLgpi4jyoRrmGY\"",
   "id": "gVLsVj7BebE",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT4M2S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": false,
    "projection": "rectangular"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Is it possible to to put the videos:list code into my current function, or would you recommend I create a new function? How would I get the duration for multiple videoID's from my serches instead of just one?

Comment: @user11721344, for get the duration of multiple videos, you need to use the `video.list` request - as user johnh10 mentioned and, in the *`id`* parameter add the `videoId`s separated by comma. Read the linked documentation in johnh10's answer.